# Outputting values 1 to A, with B values per row (Java)

Tags: java

```
public static void applicationB(int A, int B) {

    int number = 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < A; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < B; col++) {

            int output = number + row++;
            System.out.printf("% 4d", output);

        }

        // does it skip because of this?
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

It outputs with A = 20, B = 5

```
1   2   3   4   5
7   8   9   10  11
13  14  15  16  17
19  20  21  22  23
```

The correct output should be

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
```

I cannot figure out how to get it to stop skipping 6, 12, and 18. 
Am I just doing this a horrible way? or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 6):

You are incrementing `row` in two places. Also, it would be easier to just have one loop, and output a line break every `B` elements (you can use `i % B` to test for this).

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following approach. Iterate over the values you want to print out, from 1 to the maximum value (`A`). Then, print a newline whenever the remainder of value divided by the number of columns (`B`) is zero.

```
for (int value = 1; value <= A; value++) {
    System.out.printf("% 4d", value);

    if (value % B == 0) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```